# How to configure ATL trace level and categories in VS2015

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2015, atl

I want to trace the ATL registrar process in a project I'm building in VS2015 (community edition). In [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/08/20/atl-and-mfc-changes-and-fixes-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx) (third paragraph) it says that the ATL/MFC trace tool has been eliminated.

Unfortunately the [VS 2015 documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhxsse89.aspx) does not reflect that change. It still talks about the trace tool (first paragraph under Remarks).

My question is how do you specify that you want to see all messages related to the ATL registrar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I studied the source code for ATL (which is installed as part of VS). In particular atltrace.h. I found this:

1. The class CTrace controls which categories are traced and the trace
   level
2. The static unsigned member m_nLevel is the trace level.
3. Lower values of m_nLevel cause more tracing.
4. Zero causes all traces to be output
5. The value CTrace::DisableTracing explicitly disables all
       tracing
6. The static unsigned member, m_nCategory, is a bit mask
7. The template class CTraceCategoryEx pre-defines 23 different categories
8. TraceUser and TraceUtil categories are both 0x80000. I think this is a bug and TraceUser should be 0x800000
9. CTrace::GetLevel() gets current trace level. Default is zero
10. CTrace::SetLevel() sets trace level
11. CTrace::GetCategories() returns category bit mask
12. CTrace::SetCategories() sets category bit mask
13. For a given trace level and category CTrace::IsTracingEnabled() returns enablement
14. CTrace::RegisterCategory() registers a category with given name and index
15. There are 9 slots for user defined categories.
16. If _DEBUG is not defined before atltrace.h CTrace is not defined.
17. There's less than twenty or so comments in 670 lines of code.
18. Not more than 5 comments are useful in understanding code operation
19. There is a bizarre enum in CTrace that defines several unrelated constants.
20. The constant EnableAllCategories (unsigned int as bit mask) and DisableTracing (unsigned int) happen to have the same values and one is assigned to the other.

Answer to my question: nothing is needed to see all tracing related to Registrar, except debug build, and something to view messages, like DebugView.

Comment: *"There's less than twenty or so comments in 670 lines of code."* - Uhm. That's great. Thanks for sharing. May I be so inquisitive as to ask, how this (and the following bullet points) are helpful, or even remotely related to the question?

Comment: It's reasonably likely that someone searching for info on ATL tracing will hit this question. I've often found related info (but not direct answers) to questions I have in researching programming questions. If this occurs while someone is researching for related reasons, then the comments are useful background before they begin their endeavor.

Comment: How is *"There's less than twenty or so comments in 670 lines of code"* or  *"Not more than 5 comments are useful in understanding code operation"* useful to a future visitor, though? Unless they happen to perform a survey specifically on your opinion on comment quality in the ATL trace implementation.

Comment: From the Stack Overflow [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour): *"Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run **by you** [...]"* Obviously I do care about the quality of posts that I happen to come across. And I pointed out, how to improve yours. As for your final conclusion: If you use a tool like DebugView, you don't need to know any of your findings. Those are relevant if you decide to use a more appropriate tool, like the *ATL/MFC Trace Tool*.

Comment: Actually you didn't point out how to "improve" my post until the last message. And you still don't have any insight - that I see - how the comments may be useful. As for my final conclusion I didn't know that at the outset. Laying out my findings, I assert, may be useful to someone in the future.

Comment: "Lower values of m_nLevel cause more tracing." - seems like it's the opposite. From MSDN: "level can be 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4. The default, 0, reports only the most serious problems." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhxsse89.aspx