# Use CTrace::SetLevel for a MFC project that is using a shared MFC core DLL

Tags: debugging, mfc, visual-studio-2019

I have a MFC project using the shared MFC DLL (MFC140UD.DLL).

I want to set the trace level in my debug version to level 4, to get more information about message pumping.

But using `CTrace::SetLevel` in my code, just sets the debug level for the CTrace object in my personal modules (my EXE file). `CTrace` ist declared as `__declspec(selectany)`. In the exported symbols of the MFC140UD.LIB I can see no export for the class `CTrace` or its members.

So using `CTrace::SetLevel` has no effect on the MFC core MFC140UD.DLL. I always have to set a breakpoint inside the atltrace.h and need to modify the static m_nLevel value in the debugger.

Is there any trick to access the `CTrace::m_nLevel` value inside the MFC core DLL from my outer MFC EXE?

Note: Also the old `AtlTraceTool` stuff isn't no longer working and supported.

Comment: Maybe [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689450/how-to-configure-atl-trace-level-and-categories-in-vs2015) makes some help.

Comment: No. This doesn't cover my problem and I know how to use the tracing stuff. If I would use staical linking of the MFC everything would be OK. But I use the MFC as a shared DLL.

Answer (score 2):

It should be impossible to access the CTrace::m_nLevel value inside the MFC core DLL from your outer MFC EXE. Each module has its own instance of the CTrace class, that is, you should get the static member variable CTrace::m_nLevel set to the appropiate value in the context of each module. So I'm afraid you cannot configure the trace level in MFC140UD.DLL from your own module when you using the shared MFC DLL.

You can try to call API AtlTraceModifyModule to Set trace level of MFC140UD.dll.

Comment: I see no such function "AtlTraceModifyModule" in VS-2019